# what is dollar sign do in the manifest.xml

Tags: java, android

**Some explanations**

I was looking for gaining administration permission from user in android and found [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html). In Developing a Device Administration Application section it gives the text below for the manifest.xml file.

```
<activity android:name=".app.DeviceAdminSample"
            android:label="@string/activity_sample_device_admin">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver android:name=".app.DeviceAdminSample$DeviceAdminSampleReceiver"
        android:label="@string/sample_device_admin"
        android:description="@string/sample_device_admin_description"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin_sample" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**The question**

What is '.app.DeviceAdminSample$DeviceAdminSampleReceiver' and what is dollar sign in middle of it? 
I'd read some other questions about dollar sign in java but i think mine is a bit different with them.

Comment: it's for the qualified name of `DeviceAdminSampleReceiver`, a nested or inner class of `DeviceAdminSample`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the same case as other occurances of `$` in Java qualified names: `DeviceAdminSampleReceiver` is an inner class located in `DeviceAdminSample`

Comment: @VinceEmigh the page said nothing about `DeviceAdminSampleReceiver` and there is no such class inside it's snippets too. unfortunately android developer site is very unclear sometimes.

Comment: @MohhamadLord https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.java#1059

Comment: @VinceEmigh so the problem is the guide page which shows `public class DeviceAdminSample extends DeviceAdminReceiver` not `public class DeviceAdminSampleReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver`

Comment: Yup, the guide forgot to suffix the identifier with `Receiver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think dollar sign should be the same as java,the later one is the previous inner class,maybe you just think more.

Comment: There were no such inner class in snippets though.

Comment: there is such a dialog in your post developer website about "DeviceAdminReceiver","Your Device Administration application must include a DeviceAdminReceiver subclass."and that subclass should within DeviceSampleAdmin and as a inner class.